# Non-standard number data types in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-design, datatypes

I'm not sure that this question belongs to this StackExchange.

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239670/non-standard-number-data-types-in-oracle) on StackOverflow:

> Besides the "usual" number data type where precision is greater then scale there are many "non-standard" number data types where scale greater then precision or where scale is negative.
>
> For example
>
> NUMBER(2, 5) means that there are 5 digits in the fractional part, 3
> of them is obligatory zeros. NUMBER(2,-6) Here the scale is -6, which
> means the value is rounded to millions and the precision is 2, so 2
> significant digits can be stored. Can somebody provide examples of
> using such data types in practice?

Some clarifications:

I am very interested in the motivation for using such data types (NUMBER(2, 5) and NUMBER(2,-6)).

What tasks can such a table design solve?

Answer (score -2):

It prevent Aoplicatuions from inserting invalid data. P.For example for many currecncies it maks no senes to have more than 2 digits right from the decimal point.